# Why after enable paging specific address is not available?

Tags: assembly, x86, paging, att, osdev

I just want to fully understand how paging works on practice.
part of my code for paging:

```
  .section .bss
  .align 4096
p4_table:
    .skip 4096
p3_table:
    .skip 4096
p2_table:
    .skip 4096
```

and more code:

```
set_up_page_tables:

movl $p3_table, %eax
orl $0b11, %eax       // present + writable
mov %eax, (p4_table)
movl $0b10000011, (p3_table)


movl $1, %ebx
movl $0b10000011, %eax
movl %eax, p3_table(,%ebx,8)


movl $1, %ebx
movl p3_table, %eax
movl %eax, p4_table(,%ebx,8)
```

Here I fill two entries in p3_table(PDPT). And I fill two entries in p4_table(PML4). As I understand one entry in p3_table encodes 1g, and one entry in p4_table encodes 512g. Since I filled 2 entries in the p3_table with 0b10000011 it encodes addresses form 0x0 - 0x80000000(0-2g). And I place p3_table in second entry of p4_table it must encode addresses from 0x8000000000-0x8080000000(512g-514g). And if I run my program(kernel) 0-2g addresses is available, but why addresses from 0x8000000000-0x8080000000(512g-514g) not available and lead to crash?

full sources: https://github.com/JustVic/kernel_for_testing

Comment: What are `p3_table` and `p4_table`? How do you set up the CPU registers that use them?

Comment: p4_table is PML4. p3_table is PDP. You can see how I set up it in boot.s file in function "enable_paging" in full sources link to github.

Comment: p4_table, p3_table, p2_table declared in the end of boot.s file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I just forget this line `orl $0b11, %eax` then fill second entry of p4_table. It must be like this:

```
movl $1, %ebx
movl p3_table, %eax
orl $0b11, %eax
movl %eax, p4_table(,%ebx,8)
```